# opencart taxes as discount

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, tax

I am using opencart version 2.1.0.1.

I want to set different tax values to products for different countries. It's ok but when i want to give tax a negative value, it doesn't works.

Is this possible to use negative value on taxes by changing the code? I want to apply some discounts by tax. Please help.

Tax.php like this:

```
<?php
class ModelTotalTax extends Model {
    public function getTotal(&$total_data, &$total, &$taxes) {
        foreach ($taxes as $key => $value) {
            if ($value > 0) {
                $total_data[] = array(
                    'code'       => 'tax',
                    'title'      => $this->tax->getRateName($key),
                    'value'      => $value,
                    'sort_order' => $this->config->get('tax_sort_order')
                );

                $total += $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error when you add - values from the admin panel?

You can also duplicate the tax module (don't forget to change `class ModelTotalTax` to something else in your new module, like `class ModelTotalDuplicated`) and edit the code, specifically this line you'd want to change (in your duplicated module):

```
$total += $value;
```

to

```
$total -= $value;
```